# Conexion remota con Connector/ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc

estoy intentando configurar una conexión en remoto, a través de ODBC, para conectar una base de datos que está en un equipo a Excel. Todos los tutoriales que veo son de conexiones en Local, pero lo que no veo es cómo hacer esta conexión en remoto. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Comment: Para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Qué has probado? ¿Has instalado el origen de datos ODBC de MySQL en tu equipo? ¿Has configurado el origen de datos ODBC? ¿Te funciona el origen de datos? ¿Lo que te falla es acceder a los datos a través de Excel? ¿En qué parte exacta del proceso estás atascado?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres hacer directamente desde Excel y conectarte a mysql [Aqui](https://www.devart.com/odbc/mysql/excel-mysql-odbc-connection.html) está la opción, donde dice Server colocas la IP o nombre del servidor, es importante que el equipo tengan las credenciales de autorización para acceder a ese servidor

Adicionalmente y como material extra, si lo quieres hacer dentro de un lenguaje de programación a utilizar, yo en php utilizando pdo, me conecto a un ODBC de la siguiente forma:

```php
<?php
$dsn = 'odbc:nombre_del_dsn;Server=nombre_del_servidor_remoto;Database=nombre_de_la_base_de_datos_EXCEL'; 
$usuario = 'nombre_de_usuario';
$contrasena = 'contrasena'; 

try {
    $conexion = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena);
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo 'Conexión exitosa';

    // Sergio aquí es donde realizas la consultas SQL

    $conexion = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error de conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

...y si vas a utilizar el ODBC creandolo desde el codigo de programacion, seria asi:

```php
`<?php
$ruta_excel = '/rutaCompletaAlArchivo/excel.xls'; 
$dsn = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};Dbq=' . $ruta_excel; 
$usuario = '';
$contrasena = '';

try {
    $conexion = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena);
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo 'Conexión exitosa';

    // Sergio aquí es donde realizas la consultas SQL

    $conexion = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error de conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```